# Xamarin iOS: Why required to call StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource and release it in the DocPicker Sample

Tags: xamarin, locking, uidocumentpickervc, document-provider

I am using Document Picker in Xamarin iOS. In the sample of the DocPicker, they called something like StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource with comment on top.

> // IMPORTANT! You must lock the security scope before you can
>     // access this file.

Why do they have to lock this file? Is it prevent the file from modify from somewhere else while accessing the file.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS (and MacOS sandboxed apps), accessing an *external* document, a document that is outside of your own app's sandbox, requires special permission that is tracked by the OS. So once you have a NSUrl that points to an external file, you actually do not have access to it until you definitively ask for it as there is an security/resource overhead in doing so,

**Note**: Make sure that you call `StopAccessingSecurityScopedResource` otherwise your app leaks kernel-based resources (`try`/`finally` is a wise coding pattern here)

> In iOS, apps that open or move documents using a UIDocumentPickerViewController also receive security-scoped URLs.
>
> To gain access to a security-scoped URL, you must call the startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() method (or its Core Foundation equivalent, the CFURLStartAccessingSecurityScopedResource(_:) function). For iOS apps, if you use a UIDocument to access the URL, it automatically manages the security-scoped URL for you.

Ref: [Security-Scoped URLs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl)

Comment: What happened with two device accessing the file and both of them modified the same file e.g. One added a string of "Me" and the other remove "A" will there be a problem.

Comment: @Simon Two devices? Are you talking about a "cloud"-based resource being modified by two different devices at the same time? And which cloud service?

Comment: sorry i am very new to this.. Yea the file in the cloud

Comment: Which cloud service?

Comment: "For iOS apps, if you use a UIDocument to access the URL, it automatically manages the security-scoped URL for you." Oh thanks lord I had missed this important sentence.